# Consulta NFE site http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consultaRecaptcha.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=

Tags: web-service, aplicação-web, nfe, recaptcha, captcha

Utilizava para alimentar o meu sistema com os dados da nota informando o a chave da nota e o captcha,

Porém com a mudança para o reCaptcha não está mais sendo possível.

Como posso fazer isso utilizando o WebService em PHP ?

Alguém tem algum exemplo

Comment: O objetivo de captchas é justamente fazer com que o que você quer seja impossível. Como não era suficiente, mudaram para o reCaptcha que é mais elegante e seguro. Se você conseguir burlar o reCaptcha, metade do mundo vai querer te dar um emprego de mais de 100 mil dólares por ano - a outra metade vai querer te ver atrás das grades.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque busca por **solução pronta** para burlar mecanismo de proteção. Caso esteja implementando algo próprio e tenha dificuldade específica em alguma etapa, clique em [edit] para adequar a questão para o problema que está enfrentando, dentro do [escopo do site](/help/on-topic).